# Webforms - Is it safe to allow users to upload attachments?

Tags: webforms, files

Is it safe to include a 'File' type field into a webform that allows users (anonymous or authenticated) to upload their files? After reading few articles on the web , it seems it makes a website vulnerable to hacking and malware.

I would like to know better about this so that I can make a decision on this and provide an answer for and against using it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a security advisory from drupal.org that explains some of the dangers of letting anonymous users upload files: https://www.drupal.org/psa-2016-003

tl;dr

- Configure upload fields that non-trusted visitors, including
  anonymous visitors, can upload files with, to utilize **use the private
  file system**.
- Consider forcing users to **create accounts** before
  submitting content.
- **Audit** your public file space to make sure that
  files that are uploaded there are valid.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Wim. It means that it would make it safer by following all the 3 points and not by only utilising the private file system since people can still attach malicious pdfs.

Comment: Exactly, and preferably have people create an account before they can upload.

Comment: Even if you force users to create an account, the files should still not be placed in the public filesystem. Just because they took the time to register does not mean they can be trusted. Only let trusted users use the public filesystem.

Comment: @Neograph734 I agree and I too had the same thought. Thanks for your response